# xUnit exceptions fails

Tags: c#, xunit

I dont know why my unit tests fails:
Method under test:

```
public async Task<MyType> Get(string externalId)
{
    if (externalId == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (externalId == "" || externalId == " ")
        throw new FormatException();
        // ...
}
```

Unit test:

```
Action action = async () => await controller.Get(null);

// Act & Assert
action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
```

And there is fail because the error message says:

> Expected a ArgumentNullException to be thrown but no execption was thrown.

And it is strange, because while debugging this test the exception line was thrown!

I'm using xunit and fluentasserttions.

Comment: Why does your unit test contain your prod code? I suspect you've copied and pasted the wrong thing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're not awaiting action, so the exception is not observed even though it occurs. Use Func<Task> instead of Action and await it, then the exception will be observed.

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
Action action = async () => await controller.Get(null);
```

It creates an `async void` method, which makes it extremely difficult to observe exceptions (and thus do proper testing).

[Last time I checked](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Presentations/tree/3314ce9bfd47697c4f46f47d38b620d21a4069d1/Async%20Unit%20Testing), Fluent Assertions only supports an anti-pattern style of "asynchronous" assertions:

```
sut.Awaiting(…).ShouldThrow<T>();
```

Unfortunately, this uses the blocking sync-over-async hack, so it's [bound to fail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) when used with a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`. Oh, and guess [which unit testing framework provides a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Presentations/tree/3314ce9bfd47697c4f46f47d38b620d21a4069d1/Async%20Unit%20Testing)? If you guessed xUnit, then you get a prize.

So, the "asynchronous" FA tests won't work with xUnit out of the box. You have a couple of options.

You can avoid xUnit's context by running your entire test on a thread pool thread; this is inefficient, but will get the job done:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  controller.Awaiting(c => c.Get(null)).ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
});
```

Not exactly pretty.

Alternatively, you can use your own async-compatible assertions, like [the one I wrote](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Testing):

```
await AsyncAssert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => controller.Get(null));
```